# Building a Profile Screen like Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

So I'm in the process of building an application on iOS that requires a very similar profile view like Instagrams (for iOS). My question is what is the best way to do this - Instagram's profile screen consists of a personal view with your picture, stats, etc. as well as a tab bar like control that allows you to switch between multiple views underneath your personal view. These views are either a table view or a collection view. I am able to swap the view at the bottom between different table views/collection views but instagram has it setup where the whole profile screen scrolls as one scroll view or table view. How do I achieve this or what is the best way to go about building this out?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding all of the content inside a scroll view. in addition, that is now how you ask a question in SO. your question is not programming related, it is related to design and also you haven't showed what you have tried and didn't work which you need help with.

Comment: I understand it's not an appropriate question. I've tried putting everything into a single scroll view. The problem is that having a table view and/or collection view in a scroll view makes weird things happen as both the scrolling should happen on the scroll view and not the table view. But then, how we I determine the content size of the scroll view based on the full height of table view + personal view? @XCodeMonkey

Comment: from what i see the instagram is just a table view with custom cell views and a bunch of labels and in all it is a tab bar app design. you have the name of the user as the header flushed to left then you have an image that they post in a cell under that and as the footer you have the likes section. i suggest you put together a custom cell table view together and play with the size and content till you get what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have add that whole view into a **scrollview**.

Disabled the scrolling of tableview which has multiple posts.

After that, change the frame of tableview according to its row or number of counts in array.
Like,
You have 10 posts for showing in table view. and height of row for that tableview is 100.
So,

```
tableview.frame = CGRectMake(tableview.frame.origin.x, tableview.frame.origin.y, tableview.frame.size.width, 100*10);
```

After that, change the content size of scrollview.

```
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myScrollView.frame.size.height,
                                  tableview.frame.origin.y + tableview.frame.size.height);
```

**--Or--**

If your TableView's height is changing with every cell, then just use following line:-

```
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myScrollView.frame.size.height,
                                  tableview.frame.origin.y + tableView.contentSize.height);
```

Then you got the view same as profile view of Instagram.

**Don't forgot to disable scrolling of tableview.**

I am sure that, this solutions helps you.

Comment: when i add this code to my project all ui not working. ex: UIButton not clickable. scrollview views not scrolled in cell. 
at first two cell not problem but other all cells not working i think this answer probably wrong.

Comment: Its working properly..!! But Might be your issue comes from other views. Means I think there is a view on your tableview or scrollview. Please try again. I am sure, it help you.

Comment: i try my code other view controller and same ui views. and i copy uiview into scrollview and set frame size this code ui elements not clickable. and i debug with there is no view on my tableview or scrollview. and i try         tableView.setNeedsLayout()
        tableView.setNeedsDisplay()
but not working you should check this link->
http://cl .ly/2A1P04401m31

Comment: @NahitRüştüHeper : If your IBAction Method of see more button is not called, then you can able to say that, this is not working. But I can see into this link, button pressed properly, so I am sure that, your action method is called.
If you wants to profile screen like Instagram, then I think you have to set functionality of see more button into other way.

Comment: @NahitRüştüHeper : As you told that, first two cells are working fine, then 110% it happens due to some other view. Please check your UI designs once again. There is a view from which you have to got issue.
because I saw that, into your designs, there are many view. So If you are using my answer, then you can able to set only contentsize of scrollview, but you have to do this with other view. Please try this things carefully before saying anything.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping all the stuff in UIScrollView might be a little bit heavy solution and you can face performance problems in future. You may add user's profile info and tabs switch to a header view of your table view and switch datasources on click.

I've also faced the similar requirements on a project and the problem was in performance. When you try reproduce instagram behavior in autoplaying videos on scrolling... UIScrollView approach might become messy.

You might also consider AsyncDisplayKit integration to achieve a great performance.

Regards, Sergey

Comment: "switch datasources on click" do you  mean adding collection view to a cell under the header, and changing the content of collection view every time user clicks the section tab?